# Camel Route setup for testing based on static property value

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am trying to introduce Unit testing in the interface layer.
In code we provide `<from:sedaQueueName>` and camel parses the message and send it to external systems.
I want to change the route `<to:ExternalSystem>` to `<to:PrintMessageOnScreen>`.
I am already using a static global value `isUnitTest`  to get database connection outside the container.
Is there a way I can use the same variable value in application Context to decide my route?
I can access the property value using Spring SL like this:

```
<bean id="forTesting" class="test.UnitTest">
        <property name="isUnitTest">
            <value>#{T(test.UnitTest).isUnitTest}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I am not sure how to read this property inside a camel route and decide my route based on its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `dynamic router` just check the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html), or you can use the content based router here its [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html)